# Windows грузит процессор во время простоя

Tags: windows

По неизвестным для меня причинам, Windows грузит процессор во время простоя. Компьютер гремит как паровоз, на мои действия реагирует или с очень длительными задержками или не реагирует вообще. При этом обновления я приостановил через параметры. Что может так нагружать процессор особенно во время простоя? Во время работы таких приколов не было? ОС Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC. В активном режиме работает только касперский, но никакой активности с его стороны в момент простоя не было. Вирусов на компьютере тоже нет.
Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: скачай aida посмотри, что грузит твою систему, посмотри автозагрузку

Comment: Самое первое действие - посмотреть какой процесс грузит. А так вам никто не ответит, потому что причин может быть миллион

Comment: Может обновления качает?

Answer (score 1):

Смотрим процесс который загружает систему. Если процесс не системный, то идём по его адресу и выкладываем на VirusTotal на анализ. Если же это системный процесс то возможны 2 варианта:

1. Так работает ОС. Возможно выполняет фоновые операции, а Win10 любит делать что-то на фоне, например кушать вашу ОЗУ.
2. Это зловред(возможно майнер). Оно прописывается у вас в системном процессе(обычно это может быть svchost.exe) и занимается гадкой деятельностью. Убивать svchost - плохая идея, вместе с ним упадёт система. Тут только выискивать подозрительные приложения.

Comment: Далеко не со всеми `svchost` упадёт система. Большинство из них вполне можно убивать или останавливать соответствующие службы.

Comment: Согласен, но зачастую если уж зловреда и маскируют под сервис-хост, то обязательно заставляют систему упасть при его суспенде.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1**: Проверить систему другим антивирусом (желательно в безопасном режиме и другим антивирусом). Как это делается, можно легко нагуглить. Возможно засел какой-то майнер, который не видится Касперским.

**Вариант 2**: Win10 очень любит в режиме простоя оптимизировать компьютер: производить дефрагментацию жесткого диска, перестраивать индексы, сканировать встроенным защитником файлы и т.д. (решение частично пересекается с вариантом 3, но так же гуглится способы отключения)

**Вариант 3**: Если в диспетчере задач необходимо посмотреть, что загружает процессор. Если что-то похожее на `ntoskrnl.exe`, тогда вам сюда: https://fossbytes.com/how-to-fix-high-ram-and-cpu-usage-of-windows-10-system-ntoskrnl-exe-process/ или сюда https://mywebpc.ru/windows/ntoskrnl-exe-system-gruzit-cpu-pamyat-windows-10/

Возможны и другие варианты, т.к. слишком мало входной информации.